# Solar panel output voltage drops

Tags: voltage, solar-cell

I have a 5w solar panel which shows about 20V open circuit voltage. If I connect it to a load- no current.
The voltage drops to almost zero as soon as I introduce a 2.9 ohm load. I can not detect any current at any load.
Can anyone tell me whether the panel is faulty?

Comment: Well, your panel is spec'ed to deliver 5W over a specific load under specified light conditions. If it doesn't do that: it's faulty. You will have to look up the discrete specifications, however.

Comment: How do you measure the current?, what's the voltage across (say) a 100 ohm resistor?

Comment: Your load is too high for your lighting conditions, simple as that. Please see [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=solar+panel+I-V+curve&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) If you can find the curve for your panel from the manufacturer (or find it yourself.)

Answer (score 3):

You might have a panel which has a basic characteristic like this (admittedly this is a much higher power panel but the principle is the same): -

[image]

If you go along the baseline, the panel has an open circuit voltage of about 20 volts. If you short it out it will (maybe) produce 5A or whatever your panel is rated at BUT, this is for a certain level of sunlight. If you look at VI curves under different conditions you get something like this: -

[image]

As you can probably see, in worstening sunlight conditions, the ability to deliver current is dramatically reduced (even though the open-circuit terminal voltage is roughly constant at about 20 volts).

So, make sure your meter is working correctly and look up the data sheet for the panel and calculate an appropriate load resistor and repeat the test. If you are measuring an open circuit voltage then it's highly likely that the panel is OK.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I connect this panel to a 12V battery it should be able to top up the battery. Is there any way I can tell that the panel is charging the battery?

Comment: Are you able to measure current? Try measuring the current flowing into the lead-acid battery you wish to charge. On the other hand, you will probably see a slight increase in terminal voltage across the lead-acid battery when it is charging.

Comment: The way to easily monitor current is choose a series R for  50mV at max charge current 100mV drop at short circuit current with suitable W then use a DMM

Comment: There are some variations with different polycrystalline. ..for MPT and the slope from 100% to 10% solar input.

Answer (score 3):

When using a PV consider a Load R for the input solar power.

- choose \$R=V_{MP}^2/\%P_D\$. where \$V_{MP}=~{0.70 to0.85}*Voc\$ for open cct V
- Solar Power avail. is \$1kW/m^2\$ in direct full power
- at 10% in come cloud cover sky max power Vf reduces from 85 to 70% of Voc
- with a simple PD sensor  used as a Light sensor you *could* regulate the Vf or simply choose a battery voltage about 80% of Voc

  - but for max efficiency , a MPPT regulator in high power arrays is used

  The PV equivalent circuit is a current source dependent on solar flux input but with a zener like limit for Voc.

Now you can calculate R from above.

- your example

  - @100% Solar input \$(0.85*20V)^2/(100\%*5W)=58\Omega\$ @17V , 5W
  - @10% max Solar input \$(0.70*20V)^2/(10\%*5W)=392\Omega\$ @14V, 0.5W out.
  - ## thus this is a poor match for 12V lead acid battery
  - but if you are then for SLA 13.8Vmax *300mA max for your PV , you might expect 4.1W max or 18% loss from mismatch then need a voltage limiter to cut off the charger from rising above this Voltage
  - to monitor current with a DMM consider a 50mV/250mA shunt on V- side with a series diode to protect PV and prevent reverse leakage.
  - This would be a 0.2 Ohm piece of wire you can calibrate with a power supply and Ammeter with some load or sense the voltage drop from your long cable with a twisted pair and choose conductors with 50mV drop and read as 20mV per 100mA charge current then switch to read voltage with a common V-.

---

- You can see some engineering effort is needed to match the power source to the load depending on how non-linear the load is.

  - E.g. LED is like a CC sink with a voltage that is 15% above threshold voltage , just the opposite of a PV array which drops 15% in full sun. While the apparent ideal load at full power is 58Ω @17V meanwhile a 1W LED might be 3.2V * 320mA = 1W with an ESR of 1Ω (~1/Pd), which is totally mismatched for impedance for maximum power transfer.
  - Now you can figure out how to match impedances with a step-down voltage and current regulator, but this takes some effort.
  - Alternatively you may choose a LiPo charger for PV inputs with matched input regulation. Essentially this is the result of MPPT but uses sensing and hunts for the maximum peak power point with variable input (V*I). You might understand it better by considering optimum ESR and voltage then compute the "transformed" DC voltage and Impedance ratio, just as in AC transformers.

Comment: Excellent to see this math, thank you.  I am having similar problems.  I'll work it out this way and see why I am getting these results.  In other words, I have done the experimentation, so now to take they Feynman approach:  math.  Thanks again.

Comment: How would I get the readings of 17V or 14V with neither having the solar panel at hand to measure it, nore finding a usefull datasheet?

Comment: how can you expect anything without a datasheet or panel? >  @Xenox  not possible'  This question assumed Voc =20V

Comment: I guess my first comment is a bit misleading. I was wondering how @Tony Steward got the 17V or 14V values. Because yes, the Voc is mentioned in the datasheet of my panel too, but there is nothing about the dependance of voltage to "solar input". So is there some kind of general rule of thumb or even a formula to approximate voltage output in dependance of "solar input"?

Comment: Although this was over 4 yrs ago, they have not improved much. As I indicated in the beginning of answer . Vmpt is 70 to 85% of Voc for rising Solar power input. 14V/21V= 66% Voc= Vmpt at sunset at 5% of max solar input power. but if connected to a 14V battery in full sun  would lose ~20% of efficiency . Yes there is an algorithm or curves